# Validating Alphanumeric in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, model-view-controller

I am a using DataAnnotation to validate AlphaNumeric characters in MVC for a text box. It works fine, but when I enter **`'<script type='text/javascript'>alert('This site sucks!');</script>'`** in my text box it doesn't work.

```
  [RegularExpression("^([a-zA-Z0-9 .&'-]+)$", ErrorMessage="Illegal character found in name. Please enter a valid name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

the below is my view code

```
  @Html.Raw(Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Name, new { @class = "k-textbox", @style = "width:400px" }))
  @Html.Raw(Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => p.Name))
```

some assistance can be helpful

Comment: They are not related, one is a model (Server side validation attribute) for a field to be displayed in a strong typed view, the other is just a script which is 100% client side and who knows nothing of the property named "Name"

Comment: It works in the free regex tool expresso.  This means that perhaps the validation logic is not happening in the client.

Comment: Have you tried to add the @ sign at start of expression and remove escape characters? or wrap your view code with @Html.raw?

Comment: At a guess, I believe the `.` regex symbol matches any character. You may need to escape that. Also, I associate the "k-textbox" class with Kendo UI, which does not play well with the jQuery validation plugin used by MVC. See [the Kendo docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/validation) for more.

Comment: Does not make a difference..

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is you cannot validate the above string. 
As it is a JavaScript injection attack. 
So I just handled the HttpRequestValidationExpection.

Answer (score 0):

This should match that string : `[<>A-Za-z0-9'\(\)/= !;]+` 
 
You can check out this site that allows you to debug your regex : http://www.regexr.com/